# Title used when viewing posts you've flagged

Tags: feature-request

I think the title is incorrect, I see "Flagged Posts for user3791372" which suggests they're my posts which are flagged by others. I'd like to suggest the title is changed to "Flagged Posts **By** [username]"

uhm, why close a question as "primarily opinion-based" when the whole point of the feature-request is opinion-based...

Comment: 6 vs half dozen...

Comment: *by* is no better semantically as it also infers that the post were created/owned *by* the user.

Comment: "Posts Flagged by <username>"?

Comment: I don't see a strong need to change it (I doubt many people are really confused). But if you do, @gla3dr is right.

Comment: "Flagged posts by [username]" is the wrong kind of disambiguation, making it unambiguously say the wrong thing.